# Update the count value in an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, react-native

I have two array of objects arr 1 and arr 2
`arr1 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 0}]  arr2 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 0}]`

Need to create the function which accepts arr1 and arr2 as arguments and compare the fruit name if its same need to update the count value based on the count input else push the value to the array

**sample output 1:**

Inputs:
`arr1 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 10}]  arr2 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 30},{fruit: 'orange',count: 20}]`

Output:
`[{fruit: 'apple',count: 40},{fruit: 'orange',count: 20}]`

**sample output2**

Inputs:
`arr1 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 15}]  arr2 = [{fruit: 'orange',count: 20}]`

Output:
`[{fruit: 'apple',count: 15},{fruit: 'orange',count: 20}]`

code that i have tried:

```
function compareAndUpdateCount(arr1, arr2) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i].fruit === arr2[i].fruit) {
            arr1[i].count = arr1[i].count + arr2[i].count;
        } else {
            arr1.push(arr2[i])
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when the array lengths are same ,if its different need help on writing the optimise code and also the reduce time complexity if we have more data

Comment: and where is the code you've tried? This is very simple to do.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: This a typical case when a paper and pen would solve your problem. Try to write or draw this algorithm. First take your first output and alter that design to fit your second output.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a setter for count in your class
Make a new array of objects temparr

```
        temparr[0] = arr1[0];
        if((arr1[0].fruit).equals(arr2[0].fruit)) {
            temparr[0].setcount(arr1[0].count+arr2[0].count);
        }
        else {
            temparr[1]=arr2[0];
        }
```

At the end u print temparr

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function groupObject(arr1, arr2) {
  const map = new Map();
  const temp = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, { fruit, count }) => {
    map.has(fruit)
      ? (map.get(fruit).count = map.get(fruit).count + count)
      : map.set(fruit, { fruit, count });
    return acc;
  }, map);

  return [...map.values()];
}

const arr1 = [{ fruit: "apple", count: 15 }];
const arr2 = [{ fruit: "orange", count: 20 }];
console.log(groupObject(arr1, arr2));

const arr3 = [{ fruit: "apple", count: 0 }];
const arr4 = [{ fruit: "apple", count: 0 }];
console.log(groupObject(arr3, arr4));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result;
if(arr1.length < 1) {
    result = arr2;
} else if(arr2.length < 1) {
    result = arr1;
} else {
var existing = [];
var arr3 = [];
    arr1.forEach(function (item, index) {
      arr2.forEach(function (item2, index2) {
        if(item.fruit === item2.fruit) {
            item.count = item.count + item2.count;
            existing.push(index2);
        } else {
        arr3.push(item);
        if(!existing.includes(index2)) {
            arr3.push(item2);
        }        
        }
      });
    });
    result = arr3;
}
```

Comment: Input that i have added but the output is not as expected
`const arr1= [{fruit: 'apple', count :10}]
  const arr2= [{fruit: 'apple', count :30}, {fruit: 'orange', count: 20}]`

Output that i'm getting 
`[{fruit: 'apple', count :40},{fruit: 'apple', count :40}, {fruit: 'orange', count: 20}]`

Comment: I edited my response

Answer (score 0):

Loop within another loop to compare all object properties and then use an if statement to sum up the counter and remove the item of the second array using `splice()`

**Try the following snippet:**

```js
var arr1 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 10}];
var arr2 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 30}, {fruit: 'orange',count: 20}, {fruit: 'apple',count: 20}, {fruit: 'banana',count: 20}];
var counter = 0;

for(obj1 in arr1){
  for(obj2 in arr2){
    if (arr1[obj1].fruit === arr2[obj2].fruit) {
      arr1[obj1].count = arr1[obj1].count + arr2[obj2].count;
      arr2.splice(counter, 1);
      counter++;
    }
  } 
}
arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2);
console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: Output should be in one array

Comment: In that case just `concat()` both arrays. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `reduce` to group the fruits along with its count, followed by a simple `map` to get the required array

```js
const arr1 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 10}] , arr2 = [{fruit: 'apple',count: 30},{fruit: 'orange',count: 20}]
const res = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.fruit]
? (acc[curr.fruit].count += curr.count)
: (acc[curr.fruit] = curr);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.keys(res).map((item) => res[item]));
```